# Sound in Java: What's the difference between javax.sound and sun.audio?

Tags: java, audio, package, javasound

I'm starting to learn how to play sounds in Java applications.

I've come across two packages that enable the programmer to do this: `sun.audio` and `javax.sound`.

What are the differences between the two? Advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `javax.sound` is the official, documented, supported, [Java Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) API.  It should be included in any 1.3+ JRE.  Use it with confidence that it will be there in the next release.
- `sun.audio` isn't (the majority of those things).  Don't use it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Something not completly related: If I only need to be able to play audio files from the program in an exact timing. No MIDI and no need to edit or manipulate the files. Do I still need to learn all of the low-level stuff of the Java Sound API, or will learning only specific topics be enough?

Comment: *"play audio files from the program in an exact timing"*  The `Clip` class can provide that, but it only handles short sound bytes.  If you need to abandon it for alternate methods, there is probably only a few of the other classes you need to look into.